# Calling functions from previously-loaded JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery. I have a JS file (super.js) containing:

```
$("#content").load("/profile");

function setHash(hash) {
   location.hash = "#/:-)/"+hash;
}
```

"/profile" loads another external JS file (profile.js) containing a call to setHash:

```
setHash('blabber');
```

But it doesn't seem to work (setHash is undefined).

Edit: setHash is called from within a function in profile.js:

```
function changePage(type) {
    setHash('bla/'+type);
}
```

How can I get "global" functions to work in JS files included in dynamically-loaded pages?

Thanks, Albert

Comment: Is `setHash` contained within a `$(document).ready(function(){})` or another closure?

Comment: Yes it is, forgot to point that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `setHash` function outside of the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.  This will make it a global function that can be called anywhere.  If it is inside a `function(){}` closure it can only be called from within that closure.  If you and up moving many functions outside the closure, I would recommend namespacing them:

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.setHash = function() { 
                  // your code 
                };

myApp.setHash(); // invocation
```

Comment: Is the browser loading the included external JS at all when using the load() method? Just try to alert() something.